# Why "npm install -g grunt-cli" doesn't work correctly?

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, gruntjs

I am having trouble using grunt in my projects. I am setting up an macos computer with version 11.0.1.
The project files (local) are in principle correct, since I use it on another computer and it works fine there.

I have been trying to solve this error for more than two days, the problem is that the local configuration does not work correctly, since I get the message ~ bash: grunt command not found when trying to initialize grunt with the `grunt` or `grunt watch` command

When trying to install grunt-cli globally I get this error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path /Users/bertanicolau/.npm-packages
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/Users/bertanicolau/.npm-packages'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! /Users/bertanicolau/.npm/_logs/2020-11-23T17_06_23_295Z-debug.log
```

The `.npm-packages` folder does not exist in this location, instead the `.npm` folder does exist, I don't know why it is looking for another.

I've tried clearing the npm cache, I've also tried deleting the package-lock.json file and changing paths on .bash-profile but none of this seems to work.

Can it be a npm or node version bug?

```
$ npm -v && node -v
7.0.8
v15.2.1
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's `.npm-packages`? NPM installs things to `node_modules` based on the ingormation in `package.json`, locked to the versions indicated in `package-lock.json` if there is one. If you install globally (for which there is no reason anymore, given that `npx` comes with node and has done so for quite a few versions) then they still go in `node_modules`, just in npm's special global data dir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one of your `.npmrc` files, you probably have `prefix=/Users/trott/.npm-packages`. If so, leave it and create the directory with `mkdir ~/.npm-packages`. Or set it to a different directory. Or remove the entry entirely.

The [places to look for the `.npmrc` file](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/npmrc) that may be causing this to happen:

> - per-project config file (/path/to/my/project/.npmrc)
> - per-user config file (~/.npmrc)
> - global config file ($PREFIX/etc/npmrc)
> - npm builtin config file (/path/to/npm/npmrc)